# Google Sheets Filter function w/ other function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I have two columns of data, one with names (A7:A), and one with percentages (B7:B).

I am trying to use the filter function to show me the names of results with non-zero percentages. I also want to change what it spits out to have **only** cells in column B be multiplied by a value in a specific cell (B2) but keep column A the same.

Things tried:

```
=filter(A7:B,B7:B>0)
```

This works to filter out zero results but doesn't change column B

```
=FILTER($A$7:B*B2,N(B7:B)>0)
```

This changes column B to the desired value, but column A has #VALUE!
error since it's a word and can't be multiplied by a number

```
=filter(A7:B,(B7:B>0)*(B7:B*B2))
```

This gives the right name values but keeps the original percentage
values and doesn't change it.

```
=FILTER(A7:B*B2,B7:B>0)
```

This gives the right number values but gives #VALUE! error for name as  it is not a number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two methods come to mind:

#### Array

```
={FILTER($A$7:A,B7:B>0),FILTER($B$7:B*B2,B7:B>0)}
```

#### Query

```
=QUERY(A6:B,"SELECT A, B*" & B2  & " WHERE B > 0 AND A IS NOT NULL LABEL A 'Recipe', B* "& B2 &" 'lbs'", 1)
```